# making sure a thread performs work last time

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess

Finally I was able to spawn multiple subprocesses and getting their stdout into python in real-time using threads.

I have a list of dicts which contains all the data structures I need to spawn the subprocesses and the thread that reads from the pipe. The particular program I want to run takes hours to complete so I can live with the fact that stdout is only flushed every 4096bytes.

so Here is some stripped code:

```
from time import sleep
import subprocess
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue, Empty

def enqueue_output(out, queue):
    for line in iter(out.readline, b''):
        queue.put(line)
    out.close()

def queue_get_all(queue):   
    items = [] 
    while True:
        try:
            items.append(queue.get_nowait())
        except Empty, e:
            break
    return items

worklist=[
    {
        'cmd'     :r'command 1',
        'pid'     :None,
        'queue'   :None,
        'thread'  :None
    },{
        'cmd'     :r'command 2',
        'pid'     :None,
        'queue'   :None,
        'thread'  :None
    },{
        'cmd'     :r'command 3',
        'pid'     :None,
        'queue'   :None,
        'thread'  :None
    }
]


for work in worklist:
    work['pid'] = subprocess.Popen(work['cmd'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,bufsize=0)
    work['queue'] = Queue()
    work['thread'] = Thread(target=enqueue_output, args=(work['pid'].stdout, work['queue']))
    work['thread'].daemon = True
    work['thread'].start()


finalflush = False
while True:
    for work in worklist:
        lines = queue_get_all(work['queue'])
        for line in lines:
            print line

    if all(item['pid'].poll() is not None for item in worklist):
        if finalflush == False:
            sleep(10)
            finalflush = True
            continue
        else:
            break

for work in worklist:
    work['pid'].wait()
```

so the problem I am facing is that once all processes have finished and thus `all(item['pid'].poll() is not None for item in worklist)` is true. There can still be some information in the stdout pipe which hasn't been read yet by my thread. 
My hack fix is to wait 10 seconds once all subprocesses have finished and then run the loop one last time. This probably won't ever lead to any problem but I don`t really like it that way and I wonder if I could make a real fix so my thread is forced to read once more after the fact that the subprocesses have finished!

Comment: Couldn't you just `join()` each thread?

Comment: how so? doesn`t the thread continue it`s work(e.g read from the stdout I piped) even though the subprocess has finished.

Comment: Right, the thread will keep working until it gets an EOF from `out.readline`, which is what you want, isn't it? Does the stdout buffer only get flushed if you call `work['pid'].wait()` *after* the ten second sleep? Does it work if you just do the `sleep`? or just do the `wait`? What if you call `work['pid'].stdout.flush()`?

Comment: I didn`t realize my stdout would generate a EOF. the stdout buffer gets flushed every 4096 bytes and on program exit. calling stdout.flush() on it makes no difference as windows buffers it... The wait I put in was just so the thread can finish reading. but if an EOF is generated I can indeed just use `.join()`